# Change webpage font weight for Mac OS (compared Windows, Linux)

Tags: css, webfonts

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421788/if-not-my-operating-system-change-css-jquery), but didn't actually provide a solution, and the issue was reversed from my problem.

So I'm using Roboto Slab with 400 weight, 1em size, which renders nicely on Windows but incredibly thick on OS X.

I only realised this when I bought a MacBook Air.

Is there a way I can reduce the weight if a user is viewing on OS X? Or something like em (vs px) for weight?

Comment: The accepted answer for this question should help you out. Quite a bit of extra work for just the font weight, but if nothing else works for you it might be worth a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247648/can-i-code-css-specifically-for-mac-browsers

Comment: That site suggests instead using a different tool which not only appears to offer browser detection, not OS detection, but also says not to use it. Huh.

Comment: The reason it says that is because the writer didn't feel like keeping up with the constant browser/OS updates. Using `navigator.platform` or `navigator.userAgent` can get you the info on what system is being used to view your page. Like I said, probably a lot of work, but if you're hell bent on making it happen, this is the only way I know of...

Answer (score 0):

[Type Rendering Mix](http://typerendering.com/) can help you out. It detects which text rasterizer and antialiasing your browser is using, so you can tweak your font styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to your problematic font.